# canvas to svg converting in fabricjs has problems

Tags: javascript, html, svg, fabricjs

After design on canvas in fabricjs i convert it to SVG.but there is a problem with converting itext.itext is misplaced.how to  solve this problem.any idea or example would be apriciated.thank you.

before convert
[image: before convert]

after convert
[image: after convert]

Comment: Can you make a jsFidlle with the code?

Comment: There is a bug with itext in fabricjs old version.I upgraded to new version and the problem is solved.thank you.